# Fetching values of components in JPanel

Tags: validation, dynamic, components, jpanel, fetch

I have two JPanels in a Jframe. The upper panel has one JCombobox. The lower panel is dynamically populated by various components on basis of the selection in combobox in upper panel. The type and number of components to be added to lower panel is always dynamic. An example below -

Lower JPanel:

JLabelA: JCombobox

JLabelB: JCombobox + JTextfield

JLabelC: JCombobox1 + JCombobox2 + JCombobox3

JLabelD: JList

A user can select/type in values in desired components and then click on a Submit button. On the click of button. I need to do custom validation (e.g. some components are mandatory, some optional and in case of JLabelC above, values have been selected in all the three comboboxes). Once all the validation is passed, I need to fetch the user selected/provided values in the lower panel. Note that the names of components in lower panel are not fixed, so I can not directly fetch the values. One approach is to traverse all the components in the lower panel one by one and pick the values. This does not seem very efficient since I will need to traverse all while I need to traverse only those where user has provided some input.

Queries-

1) How can we attach the validations to components (as we can do in JavaScript validations)?

2) Please suggest alternate approaches for fetching the values of components.

Comment: Can you keep references to the comboboxes, etc. while you're creating/laying out the components?

Comment: Yes I can. But the issue that I see there is- how am I going to differentiate between two JTextFields or JcomboBoxes? The four component combinations given in example above are four 'types' and each such ‘type’ can appear multiple times in the panel. The code to create each ‘type’ is same and is invoked multiple times. Am I clear?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen (legacy) code that traversed JComponents and bound/unbound a multi-purpose listener to combo-boxes, text-fields, etc. I recall it working (it was for attaching "dirty" listener to all the editable widgets to that prevent the user from leaving unsaved changes behind).

If you want to do real-time validation, you can attach ChangeListeners or ActionListeners to the JComboBoxes or JLists and DocumentListeners to the JTextField documents. I've tried using InputVerifiers, but it's usually a problem for the user when you screw around with component focus.